# What does this symbol in notification bar mean?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

What does the circled symbol below mean?

[image]

Comment: Please see: [Meaning of 3/4 broken circle icon?](/q/128833/16575) and [3/4 circle with plus in it?](/q/169883/16575).

Comment: @Izzy thank you, I just saw that first question right before you posted the comment :)

Comment: Happens :) If you're as much around on this site as I am, you're easier to remember what already has been asked – and with some luck also how to find it :)